# Detection color on image

Tags: opencv

I would like to implement detection of object on image. The detection must be fast as it is possible so the only thing I consider is color. ( color of object is unique). But, we know that color can differ between real object and object on image. So algorithm has to take into account this difference.

The object I consider is here:
[image]

I prefer solution with using OpenCV but it is not necessary.

Comment: and what have you done? stackoverflow is a place to ask questions about a problem you are having not to ask for code. In google you can find a bunch of tutorials such as [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/) one

Comment: so you know the desired color (with some difference) - the pinkt color in the example. And do you know that there is an object of that color in the image (so you want to find it where exactly it is in the image) or do you not know whether there is an object of the desired color in the image and you want to decide whether it is?!?

Comment: That example image has multiple 'pink' colour values, how do you want to deal with that at the same time as believing that the objects value is 'unique'? Now that you're dealing with a range of colours, how are you going to remove false positives from the results? What will the background/image-context be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the programming language you're using. This is a python+OpenCV code to implement colour thresholding using trackbars:

```
import cv2

def nothing(x): #needed for createTrackbar to work in python.
    pass    

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow('temp')
cv2.createTrackbar('bl', 'temp', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('gl', 'temp', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('rl', 'temp', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('bh', 'temp', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('gh', 'temp', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('rh', 'temp', 255, 255, nothing)
while true
        ret,img=cap.read()#Read from source
        bl_temp=cv2.getTrackbarPos('bl', 'temp')
        gl_temp=cv2.getTrackbarPos('gl', 'temp')
        rl_temp=cv2.getTrackbarPos('rl', 'temp')
        bh_temp=cv2.getTrackbarPos('bh', 'temp')
        gh_temp=cv2.getTrackbarPos('gh', 'temp')
        rh_temp=cv2.getTrackbarPos('rh', 'temp')
        thresh=cv2.inRange(img,(bl_temp,gl_temp,rl_temp),(bh_temp,gh_temp,rh_temp))
        if(cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('b')):
        break #break when b is pressed 
        cv2.imshow('Video', img)
        cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
```